# Does elementary OS see and use Intel Fake Raid as easily as Ubuntu does?

Tags: system-installation

I have 2 Samsung 840 Pro's that MUST be used together as one drive in RAID0. On Ubuntu it just happens out of the box with nothing to configure. But many distros never worked for me. So before I wipe Windows 10 off these drives and convert to eOS I want to make sure it just works out of the box please.

My System is a Intel x58 with ICH10R. It has a Hexa-Core Xeon CPU, and 12GB of DDR3. I have TWO Samsung 840 Pro's for the OS, and THREE Crucial C300's as one large Raid drive for the storage. After eOS is installed I only want to see two drives in total, sd0 and sd1, I assume. On Windows its drive C: and E: as expected.

Ubuntu does this by default, and so does Windows. Will latest elementary OS do the same? Or am I required to know how to set it up that way? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

elementary OS is based on Ubuntu so there are good chances that it will work the same way it does with Ubuntu. However I would suggest that you test it with a Live CD / USB so that there are no bad suprises.